# Consequences of this javascript code

Tags: javascript

I am reading the book "Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja" by John Resig and in it he is explaining how one can try to anticipate future functionality of the language by extending objects' prototypes with this code:

```
if(!Array.prototype.forEach){
   Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, callback){
      for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
         fn.call(callback || null, this[i], i, this);
      }
   };
}
```

Now, I understand that the "callback || null" statement prevents from passing a possible undefined value to the "call" function. What I do not understand is what could be the consequences of passing null as the context of the "fn" parameter. Wouldn't that make the code crash?

Thank you for any explanation and/or enlightenment you can provide.

Comment: `callback` is not a descriptive variable name. `fn` is the callback here actually, and `callback` the `this` value...

Comment: usually the name `scope` would be used where `callback` is being used. `callback` implies function to me.

Comment: `this_obj` would be a better name for this parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't cause a crash. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call:

> […] if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

(In the case of a Web-page, "the global object" is `window`.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no "real" problem with this, the context "this" is just equal to null then.
Thats a common way when using .call() or .apply() if you do not have an appropriate value for the context.

Answer (score 1):

`Function.call`'s first parameter is the scope to run the function in. If that parameter is falsey (`null` is one form of falsey) then it will run that function in the global scope. In browsers that means the function will run with `this` set to `window`.

The `callback || null` isn't needed, if you pass `undefined` in as the scope, it will use `window`. Although possibly there is some obscure browser or situation where it doesn't, which would explain why Resig did that.

Comment: scope means something [entirely different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) than what you are using it for

Comment: unfortunately the term 'scope' has become quite muddy in the JavaScript world. Many people, frameworks, libraries, etc do use the term "scope" to mean "the target of `this` when invoking a function"

Comment: In looking around, I think my favorite name for that is `context`, which is what underscore.js uses.

Comment: I know what you mean. In js-world, self-executing function doesn't imply recursion, it has somehow came to mean immediately invoked functions. "JSON objects" are thrown around in contexts that have nothing to do with JSON. And so on and so on. Scope used to mean object context is perhaps the most harmful of the bunch because it's just [so wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)).

Comment: Yup, I totally hear you. I think I will stop using the term "scope" in this sense then. My main problem is I use ExtJS at my day job, and they absolutely use the term "scope" to mean "object context", sort of baked into my brain from there.